# Compare 2 errors in Go for unit test

Tags: go

I got a problem like below: Compare 2 errors when writing unit test

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    
    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"
    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp/cmpopts"
)

func main() {
    er1 := errors.New("database name is not exists")
    er2 := errors.New("database name is not exists")
    
    result1 := reflect.DeepEqual(er1, er2)
    fmt.Println("reflect: ", result1)
    
    result2 := cmp.Equal(er1, er2, cmpopts.EquateErrors())
    fmt.Println("compare: ", result2)
    
    result3 := errors.Is(er1, er2)
    fmt.Println("errorIs: ", result3)
}
```

And the output of the above code is:

```
reflect:  true
compare:  false
errorIs:  false
```

I want to compare 2 error and `reflect.DeepEqual(er1, er2)` is the 1st approach I apply and this method produce the output I want, but this approach have a warning from `go lint`:

```
avoid using reflect.DeepEqual with errorsdeepequalerrors
```

After google search, some people tell me some approaches that are:

- Use cmp package to compare: `cmp.Equal(er1, er2, cmpopts.EquateErrors())`
- Use errors package to compare: `errors.Is(er1, er2)`

But both above approaches can not produce same result like the 1st approach (use reflect.DeepEqual).
How I can compare 2 errors without warning from `go lint` and produce the result like the `reflect.DeepEqual`
Tks

Comment: If you need a way to make "2 different errors look equal", you're probably doing something wrong, you're handling errors in the wrong way. You should use `errors.Is()`, and if that reports false, you should treat those errors to be different.

Comment: Many places the standard lib returns errors which you can compare using the `==` operator to values stored in exported variables, e.g. `io.EOF`, `csv.ErrFieldCount`. You should not need more complex logic than that.

Comment: @ThoQuach : do you intend to compare errors in unit testing code ? or in your appication's code ?

Comment: @LeGEC, that 's right, I need to compare 2 errors in unit test Golang

Comment: why not use the `github.com/stretchr/testify/assert` lib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how you write your tests, you may depend on `reflect.DeepEqual()` and ignore the linter warning ;
the drawback is : you start depending on the inner structure of the errors you return.

---

In the testing code we write, we use one of the following patterns :

- most of the time, we just compare the error to `nil` ;
- in some cases our functions return predefined error values, and we test for these specific values :

```
package pkg

var ErrUnboltedGizmo = errors.New("gizmo is unbolted")

// in test functions, depending on the case :
if err == pkg.ErrUnboltedGizmo { ...
// or :
if errors.Is(err, pkg.ErrUnboltedGizmo) { ...
```

- when our production code mandates that a specific error be spotted (a common use case is `io.EOF`), we write code that dutifully *wraps* that known error, and we use `errors.Is()` (both in production code and in testing code),
- when the need is, in testing only, to loosely confirm that an error matches something and not something else (e.g : `Parse error` and not `File not found`), we simply search for strings in the error message :

```
if err == nil || !strings.Contains(err.Error(), "database name is not exists") {
    t.Errorf("unexpected error : %s", err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I found useful is to use cmp.Diff with cmpopts.IgnoreFields to ignore the sepecific error fields which cause the issue u detailed and afterward I just run a check on the errors with string.Contains or whatever I find fitting.

So it goes something like this:

```
if diff := cmp.Diff(expected, got, cmpopts.IgnoreFields(expected, "ErrorField")); diff != "" { 
          // found diff not including the error
}
```

Now check only the errors on their own and that's it.

And yeah I know u marked a solution already but maybe it will help someone :)